# What are these specific part of technique in the Gran Jota called?

Tags: technique, classical-guitar

Here where there seems to be some sort of slapping of the bridge.

And this which I cannot even describe.

I would like to know what these techniques are called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the tambor (also spelled [tambour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tambour_(guitar_technique))) effect, allegedly used to mimic the sound of a heartbeat and typically notated with X's as noteheads. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=men30tIm7BA) a brief video.

Comment: It's marked 'tamb' on the original dots. Hitting specific strings rather than the bridge. I use a similar technique with bass guitar, giving a rather different sound to the usual pluck/snap/pop.